# extract expression as string in grammar rules instead of it being matched to other expression grammar rules python ply

Tags: python, python-3.x, grammar, bnf, ply

```
def abc_expression(p):
   expression : abc ( expression )
```

I want to extract the p[3] term as it is, instead of it to be matched to other grammar rules. For eg: my input is :

```
abc(def(hello))
```

i want to extract "`def(hello)`" by using the rule `abc ( expression )` instead of expression i.e `def(hello)` getting matched to a rule like `def ( token ).`

Please help, is it possible to extract `def(hello)` from `abc(def(hello))`, instead of expression getting matched to any other rule.

Comment: Not easily. Why do you want to do that? It's easy enough to concatenate the subtree back into a string if that's what you want to do. (Anyway, how do you propose to tell the parser which close parenthesis in the input matches the pattern without letting it analyse the expression?)

Comment: @rici i want to do this because when the expression starts with abc(...) i just want to get whatever params are passed to it. Only problem is that the params might match other grammar rules, so how do i get the params? what should i do and what should be the right way to do the same?

Comment: @rici i just want that whole string. I know i can let other expressions to get matched with it but i am returning something else from other expression functions and not the string i want. So, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to write a preprocessor? That requires a slightly different architecture. Otherwise, I'd stick with the answer that the right way to do it is to parse into an AST and do whatever you want with the subtree in context, which might be to just recreate the original string (or extract it from the input by using location information). I don't think a more concrete answer is possible here without a more concrete question.

Comment: ok, what i did is -> I created a rule like expression : abc ( expression2 )  and expression2 leading to all the same matching rules but all those matching rules fucntions returning the string. This way I am able to recreate the string. Is this what you are suggesting? what's the AST way of doing this?

Comment: An AST is a tree which describes the parse. How it does so is basically up to you, but normally the leaves are tokens and the other nodes are productions -- but not necessarily every production. You'll find examples all over the place. You can add position ranges to every token in your lexical actions, and then use that to compute position ranges for every production (from the first position of the first token to the last position of the last token); that way, it's easy to turn any tree node back into its source data.